Check if the phone has fisheye camera
On my app I need to initialize my CameraController with the fisheye camera if present, otherwise with the normal one. Currently I am retrieving the cameras like this:
final cameras = await availableCameras();

but CameraDescription doesn't contain any useful data. How can I do it?
